# restore pages - chrome issue

Tags: linux

There are many posts for this issue. I havent manage to make anything work for me. I use linux on my VMs and every time I open chrome, it come sup with the resore pages pop up, blocking my start up page. I havent managed to fix this error with any of the terminal commands posted here and elsewhere. I must say I am kindergrden using the command temrinal, but I can follow instructions fine. any help will be much appreiciated.

Comment: How is this raspberry pi related?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Chromium, but there have been reports that Google has been blocking sync on other apps. The only "solution" is to use Google Chrome (which is not available on Raspberry Pi OS).

I suggest you try other browsers - I use Vivaldi (which works better that Chromium).